# Getting the concrete class of a method called inside a delegate in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, cil

My situation is as follows - a delegate of the form

```
 () => _instanceOfMyClassWhichImplementsInterfaceIX.MyMethod()
```

is passed as a parameter to a certain method. Inside that method I need to get both the name of the method called in the delegate (in this case "MyMethod") and the actual class of the object (in this case "MyClass") _MyInstanceOfClassWhichImplementsInterfaceIX . Using the method described by user Stipo in his answer to [Find the name of the invoked method of a Func delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634006/find-the-name-of-the-invoked-method-of-a-func-delegate)  I was able to get the name of the method and the name of the **interface** ("IX" in case), but not the name of the concrete class of the object. Its to done by calling the method "GetCalledMethods" in his code, which returns a liste of MethodBase and calling methodBaseInstance.ReflectedType.Name on it.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are better off making the method accept an expression, it will make it easier to gather the info you need. Here is a way you could do that, the interface can be gotten just as easy as here I am getting the actual MethodInfo class, and the actual type it belongs to.

```
void Main()
{
    var _instanceOfMyClassWhichImplementsInterfaceIX = new MyClass();
    Expression<Func<bool>> y = () => _instanceOfMyClassWhichImplementsInterfaceIX.MyMethod();
    var methodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)y.Body).Method;
    var methodName = methodInfo.Name;
    var methodDeclaringType = methodInfo.DeclaringType;
    
    Console.WriteLine(methodName);
    Console.WriteLine(methodDeclaringType);
    Console.WriteLine(y.Compile().Invoke());
    Console.WriteLine(methodDeclaringType.GetInterface(nameof(IMyClass)));
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public bool MyMethod() => true;
}
public interface IMyClass { }
```

---

EDIT: Added to better answer the users question

```
// If you want to make the expression while referencing as a interface it will stick 
// to the expression, meaning we cant get the underlying type from it. 
// The easy way around this is trivial just pass the underlying type as a generic with a constraint. 
// If you MUST not pass in type T you can do this same method, 
// but it cant be inferred when using the method is all.
public void MethodDoThis<T>(IMyClass myclass)
    where T : IMyClass
{
    Expression<Func<bool>> y = () => myclass.MyMethod<MyClass>();
    var methodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)y.Body).Method;
    var methodName = methodInfo.Name;
    var methodDeclaringType = methodInfo.DeclaringType;

    Console.WriteLine("Method Name: " + methodName);
    Console.WriteLine("Method Declaring Type: " + typeof(T));
    Console.WriteLine("Method Return Value: " + y.Compile().Invoke());
    Console.WriteLine("Method Defined Interface: " + typeof(T).GetInterface(nameof(IMyClass)));
}
```

Comment: If you replace "var" with "IMyClass" (which is how my program works, as the instances of IMyClass are being injected) it doesn't work.

Comment: Thats because I didnt add the `MyMethod` in `MyClass` to its interface, (IMyClass) I did it strictly for example reasons, add the `MyMethod` to the interface and it will work

Comment: I did it, it doesn't work. The problem is not that I cant get the method name, but the methodDeclaringType contains the interface instead of the conctrete class.

Comment: @galmeida I added a addition to answer, I think this is what you are getting at