# Dynamically defining method C#

Tags: c#

I want to run a mathematical function (dynamic) n times...

So f(x) would be:

```
((n+0) * (n+1) * (n+2) * .... * (n+x)) / (0+1+2+...+x+(x+1))
```

Since I want to calculate n times with the function it's not efficient to recalculate the function over and over again. Is there a way to store the function in a method?

Comment: What you're describing is called "Memoization."  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20544641

Comment: There's probably a mathematical solution to simplify the expression for different values of X and N.

Comment: Does loop not satisfy your need? Or recursive call?