# C# returning Lazy function

Tags: c#

I need to write a function that takes function with one parameter as paramemer and return this function as lazy function. This code doesn't work and I have really no idea what this function should return and how I can somehow convert normal function to lazy function.

```
public static Lazy<int> memo2(Func<int, int> f1) => x => new Lazy<int>(f1(x));
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The constructor for `Lazy<int>` wants _a function that returns an integer_ as its argument but you have provided _an integer_. Perhaps you meant `new Lazy<int>(() => f1(x))`

Comment: The `Func` is defining a method that takes a parameter and returns a value.  But you want to make that `Lazy`.  So is the caller of whatever your Lazy implementation looks like supposed to supply this parameter to the `Func`?  If so, your return value will look something like `Func<int, Lazy<int>>`, which doesn't really help anything.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The canonical way to do that in C# is *not* with `Lazy<T>` (because you'd need one Lazy instance for each possible parameter value), but rather with a dictionary. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20544641/87698

Comment: Hey Bart dont forget to upvote and select a best answer

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

- `f1(x)` returns `int`
   but the constructor for `Lazy<int>` requires a `Func<int>`.
- `x => new Lazy<int>(...);` is of type `Func<int,Lazy<int>>` but your function returns `Lazy<int>`.

I'm not sure what your goal is but if you just wanted your code to compile you could do this:

```
 public static Lazy<int> memo2(Func<int, int> f1, int x) => new Lazy<int>(() => f1(x));
```

Comment: Or maybe it was intended to be `Func<int,Lazy<int>> memo2(Func<int, int> f1) => x => new Lazy<int>(() => f1(x));` ?

Comment: @Wyck Yea it's impossible to tell what the actual intent was from the question

Comment: Because we are all in the dark here as to the OP's intent, it is better to comment rather than answer, until we get ,(hopefully) some clarity.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I think my answer explains the compiler errors that OP is clearly having difficulty with